# Weird Memory Leak in iPad App

Tags: ipad, memory-leaks, iboutlet

I am having a really weird memory leak in an iPad App.

I have a Navigation Controller App, By clicking a button on the Main Controller i push a ViewController, This View Controller has a UIWebView. which is connect to the NIB file using IBOutlet.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {

     IBOutlet UIWebView *webview; 
}
```

And in the Webview when the user touches it starts playing the youtube video.

Now when i tap return button i pop the view controller back.

Here comes the problem, the video does not stop playing and the reason is the UIWebView instance is still existing, for this i checked its retain count in the dealloc method and it shows 2, but it should have been 1. I have not retained it at all in my code.

And here come the weird stuff, just for testing i called release on the object, and this time the video stopped playing.

I know this is not the right thing to do , but no answers as to why its happening such a way.

Any comment on where i am going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two points to consider:

1. How is the MyViewController allocated and released? When you push a viewcontroller, it will be retained once again. You can actually release it at that point in the code.
2. Before popping MyViewController, try to set webview's delegate to nil.

Comment: The viewcontroller is released once it is pushed to the navigation controller, and the webview has no delegate set